# Is the treatment of any type of ectopic pregnancy still called an embryectomy?

Tags: terminology, surgery, obstetrics

The generic term for the treatment of an ectopic pregnancy seems to be "[embryectomy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embryectomy)":

> <sup>ἐκ (*ek*, “out”) + τέμνω (*témnō*, “to cut”)</sup>

Stedman, [*Practical Medical Dictionary* (1916), p. 302](https://books.google.com/books?id=mRIiAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA302) calls embryectomy

> The operative removal of the product of conception, especially in ectopic pregnancy.

Anderson, K. A., L. E. Anderson, Angie Dröber, and Ute Villwock. “[E](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-01099-0_5).” In *Springer Lexikon Pflege*, edited by K. A. Anderson, L. E. Anderson, Angie Dröber, and Ute Villwock, 264–319. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer, 2002, 281:

> **Embryektomie.** Operatives Entfernen eines Embryos, z.B. bei einer ektopischen Schwangerschaft.
> [*griech.*: bryein, wachsen, ektome, ausschneiden.]
> • embryectomy
>
> ---
>
> <sub>**Embryectomy.** Surgical removal of an embryo, e.g., in an ectopic pregnancy.
> [*Greek*: bryein, to grow, ectome, to cut out.]
> • embryectomy.</sub>

However, I see the term is rarely used in recent medical literature. [A Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embryectomy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019) reveals:

[image: embryectomy Ngram]

"Salpingectomy" is much more common ([embryectomy, salpingectomy Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embryectomy%2Csalpingectomy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019)):

[image]

**Is embryectomy still the proper medical term for the treatment of any type of ectopic pregnancy, or is a different term used?**

<sup>Note: I'm interested in the generic term covering all types of ectopic (extra-uterine) pregnancies, not just those that occur in the Fallopian tube.</sup>

---

<sup>If it is a tubal ectopic pregnancy, a [salpingectomy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salpingectomy) is done, and this term is in current use in more modern medical books:</sup>

> <sup>From *salping-* (“of or relating to the salpinx [Fallopian tube]”) +‎ *-ectomy* (“surgical removal”)</sup>

<sup>which involves a simultaneous embryectomy.</sup>

---

<sup>Cf. the [etymology of "ectopic"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ectopic#Etymology):</sup>

> <sup>ἐκ (*ek*, “out”) + -topic τόπος (*tópos*, “place”)</sup>

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149069/discussion-on-question-by-geremia-is-the-treatment-of-any-type-of-ectopic-pregna).** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

The word is not and has never been used by doctors and medical researchers outside of animal studies, which probably explains why some medical dictionaries include it. Therefore, the peaks of usage shown in the Ngram must have all been found within non-medical contexts.

I draw this conclusion based on Google Scholar searches for the word "embryectomy" in four time spans: [1900-2023](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=embryectomy&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C7&as_ylo=1900&as_yhi=2023), [1900-1965](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=embryectomy&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C7&as_ylo=1900&as_yhi=1965), [1900-1960](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=embryectomy&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C7&as_ylo=1900&as_yhi=1960), and [1800-1900](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=embryectomy&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C7&as_ylo=1800&as_yhi=1900). The number of hits found for each range were 49, 4, 1, and 0, respectively. Examination of the hits did not reveal a single usage in a human medical context. There were a few animal studies that mentioned it, and some botanical studies, but nothing related to human medicine.

Comment: I suspect doctors never really used that term, regardless of Steadman's definition. I have never heard it, and I'm old. I suspect it was pushback terminology from anti-abortionists (laypeople) to lay bare the procedure. We all know what an abortion involves.

Comment: But embryectomy ≠ induced abortion (embryotomy, yes).

Comment: Not all abortions are induced medically. But I think @anongoodnurse is pretty much right. When I look at your first Ngraph I see a big spike in use of the word right about the time abortion was becoming a political issue, then a big drop right around Roe v Wade. There's another spike in the early 1980s and I suspect that's the emergence of organized anti-abortion activists. But then there's a steady downhill slide into nothingness. But when I search Google Scholar, I get a very different picture. Basically, doctors and medical researchers don't use the word and never did.

Comment: I hadn't thought to google the term. In Scholar, I see it, and think it's a reasonable term for the removal of embryos (sp?) at different stages of development. In regular Google, it's either a band, or it's changed to embryotomy. So the phrase "fell out of favor" doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: @CareyGregory My point is the embryectomy has nothing to do with abortion, whether induced or spontaneous (though the death of the embryo could result from an embryectomy).

Comment: @Geremia Tell that to the anti-abortion activists who were using the word so much when medical professionals weren't.

Comment: My apologies to the upvoter for rewriting my answer after you voted.

Comment: I had upvoted your answer before being "encouraged" to think about it more. So that vote stays, and I'm grateful for the edit.